# I am trying to pull an active user's location at any given time

Tags: android, facebook, google-places-api, foursquare

I would like to find an API that allows me to pull a client's current location. I know Google Places and FourSquare have API's available. Basically, I want it to run at all times, as I am eventually going to create a dating app that allows you to see who is at a current bar/restaurant/social setting at any given time.

The fetch for the current location will obviously have to be running at all times, and there are considerations of using too many client resources. With that being said, what are some of my options?

Comment: please take help from this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Google Places API for this: `PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace()`.  See https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/current-place (and the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start) guide).

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be exactly what I need!

Comment: Glad I could help :)